# FlexibleWidthXYPlot requires fixed width to render

Tags: reactjs, react-vis

I'm using `FlexibleWidthXYPlot` inside a component that is rendered conditionally if component should be visible and data (via props) is defined.

But the `react-vis` calculate the chart width to `width=0` (so Chart isn't displayed). I can make it calculate the width correctly by re-rendering like this:

- 1. Resize browser
- 2. Set `width` prop with fixed value.

I can't do 2. as the chart should be responsive. So I tried to trigger a resize on `componentDidMount` but no luck either:

```
public componentDidMount() {
  window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
}
```

I'm setting `xDomain` manually so I tried `dontCheckIfEmpty={true}` but it's not working either...

**Why is `FlexibleWidthXYPlot` calculating width to `0`? And how can I fix it?**

**EconomyOverview.tsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Theme, createStyles, withStyles, WithStyles, Card } from '@material-ui/core'
import SelectableTabs from './SelectableTabs'
import PaymentsChart from './PaymentsChart'
import MileageChart from './MileageChart'
import { IMileageChart, IPaymentChart } from '@omnicar/sam-types'
import * as api from 'api/api'
import notify from 'utils/notify/notify'

interface IProps {
  id: string
}

type TProps = IProps & WithStyles<typeof styles>

export type TTab = 'payments' | 'mileage'

interface IState {
  activeTab: TTab
  paymentChartData: IPaymentChart | undefined
  mileageChartData: IMileageChart | undefined
}

const styles = ({ spacing }: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      display: 'flex',
    },
    tabs: {
      width: '35%',
      display: 'flex',
    },
    content: {
      width: '65%',
      padding: spacing.unit * 2,
    },
  })

class ContractDetailsEconomyOverview extends React.Component<TProps, IState> {
  public state: IState = {
    activeTab: 'payments',
    paymentChartData: undefined,
    mileageChartData: undefined,
  }

  public componentDidMount() {
    this.loadData()
  }

  public render() {
    const { classes } = this.props
    const { activeTab, paymentChartData, mileageChartData } = this.state

    return (
      <Card className={classes.root}>
        <div className={classes.tabs}>
          <SelectableTabs
            data={{ paymentChartData, mileageChartData }}
            activeTab={activeTab}
            onTabSelect={this.handleTabSelect}
          />
        </div>
        <div className={classes.content}>
          {activeTab === 'payments' && <PaymentsChart data={paymentChartData} />}
          {activeTab === 'mileage' && <MileageChart data={mileageChartData} />}
        </div>
      </Card>
    )
  }
  private handleTabSelect = (activeTab: TTab) => {
    this.setState({ activeTab })
  }

  private loadData = async () => {
    const res = await api.getContractDetailsChartData(this.props.id)

    if (res.errorData || res.networkError) {
      notify.error()
    } else if (res.data) {
      const { paymentChart, mileageChart } = res.data
      this.setState({ paymentChartData: paymentChart, mileageChartData: mileageChart })
    }
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(ContractDetailsEconomyOverview)
```

**PaymentsChart**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { withStyles, createStyles, WithStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import {
  FlexibleWidthXYPlot,
  YAxis,
  XAxis,
  HorizontalGridLines,
  LineMarkSeries,
  LineSeries,
  DiscreteColorLegend,
  Hint,
} from 'react-vis'
import 'react-vis/dist/style.css'
import { theme } from 'theme'
import { t } from '@omnicar/sam-translate'
import { IPaymentChart, IChartDateValue } from '@omnicar/sam-types'
import { formatDate } from '@omnicar/sam-format'
import Typography from 'components/Typography'
import ChartTooltip from 'components/admin/ChartTooltip'

interface IProps extends WithStyles<typeof styles> {
  data: IPaymentChart
}

interface IState {
  tooltipValue: IChartDateValue | undefined
}

const styles = () =>
  createStyles({
    root: {},
    tooltip: {
      display: 'flex',
    },
    exVat: {
      textAlign: 'right',
      color: theme.palette.text.light,
      fontStyle: 'italic',
    },
    legend: {
      display: 'flex',
      justifyContent: 'space-between',
    },
  })

class PaymentsChart extends Component<IProps, IState> {
  public state: IState = {
    tooltipValue: undefined,
  }
  public legendItems = [
    {
      title: t('Payments'),
      color: '#40A695',
      strokeWidth: 3,
    },
    {
      title: t('Expected payments'),
      color: '#ccc',
      strokeStyle: 'dashed',
      strokeWidth: 3,
    },
    {
      title: t('Costs'),
      color: '#ED7C33',
      strokeWidth: 3,
    },
  ]

  public render() {
    const { classes, data } = this.props
    const { tooltipValue } = this.state
    const curveName = 'curveMonotoneX'

    // transform data
    const earnings = data ? this.transform(data.seriesEarnings) : []
    const costs = data ? this.transform(data.seriesCosts) : []
    const expectedEarnings = data ? this.transform(data.seriesExpectedEarnings) : []

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        {data && (
          <>
            <DiscreteColorLegend items={this.legendItems} orientation="horizontal" />
            <FlexibleWidthXYPlot
              margin={{ left: 60 }}
              height={300}
              xType="time"
              xDomain={[new Date(data.contractStartDate), new Date(data.contractEndDate)]}
            >
              <YAxis />
              <XAxis />
              <HorizontalGridLines />
              <LineSeries
                data={expectedEarnings}
                stroke="#ccc"
                fill="#ccc"
                strokeWidth={3}
                strokeStyle="dashed"
                size={3}
                curve={curveName}
              />
              <LineMarkSeries
                data={costs}
                stroke="#ED7C33"
                fill="#ED7C33"
                strokeWidth={3}
                size={3}
                curve={curveName}
                // tslint:disable-next-line jsx-no-lambda
                onValueMouseOver={(value: IChartDateValue) => {
                  this.setState({ tooltipValue: value })
                }}
                // tslint:disable-next-line jsx-no-lambda
                onValueMouseOut={() => {
                  this.setState({ tooltipValue: undefined })
                }}
              />

              <LineMarkSeries
                data={earnings}
                stroke="#40A695"
                fill="#40A695"
                strokeWidth={3}
                size={3}
                curve={curveName}
                // tslint:disable-next-line jsx-no-lambda
                onValueMouseOver={(value: IChartDateValue) => {
                  this.setState({ tooltipValue: value })
                }}
                // tslint:disable-next-line jsx-no-lambda
                onValueMouseOut={() => {
                  this.setState({ tooltipValue: undefined })
                }}
              />
              {tooltipValue && (
                <Hint value={tooltipValue}>
                  <ChartTooltip value={tooltipValue} />
                </Hint>
              )}
            </FlexibleWidthXYPlot>
            <div className={classes.legend}>
              <div>
                <Typography variant="subheading">{t('Startdate')}</Typography>
                <Typography variant="body2">{formatDate(data.contractStartDate)}</Typography>
              </div>
              <div>
                <Typography variant="subheading">{t('Duration')}</Typography>
                <Typography variant="body2">{`${data.duration.current} / ${data.duration.total}`}</Typography>
              </div>
              <div>
                <Typography variant="subheading">{t('Enddate')}</Typography>
                <Typography variant="body2">{formatDate(data.contractEndDate)}</Typography>
              </div>
            </div>
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }

  /**
   * Transforms x from string > Date
   */
  private transform = (list: IChartDateValue[]): IChartDateValue[] =>
    list.map(value => ({
      ...value,
      x: new Date(value.x),
    }))
}
export default withStyles(styles)(PaymentsChart)
```

Answer (score 5):

What worked for me was adding [react-virtualized-auto-sizer](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/AutoSizer.md), like so:

```
import React from 'react'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import { XYPlot, XAxis, YAxis, HorizontalGridLines, LineSeries } from 'react-vis'
import clsx from 'clsx'
import AutoSizer from 'react-virtualized-auto-sizer'

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  plot: {
    height: 300,
    width: '100%'
  },
  hide: {
    display: 'none'
  }
})

function TestChart({ data, hidden }) {
  const classes = useStyles()

  return (
    <div 
      className={clsx(classes.plot, {
        [classes.hide]: hidden
      })}
    >
      <AutoSizer>
        {({ width, height }) => (
          <XYPlot height={height} width={width}>
            <HorizontalGridLines />
            <LineSeries data={data} />
            <XAxis />
            <YAxis />
          </XYPlot>
        )}
      </AutoSizer>
    </div>
  )
}

export default TestChart
```

Whatever the width and height is of the parent `div`, the chart will automatically resize appropriately.